# Java no guarda List<Integer> en función recursiva

Tags: java

Tengo un problemilla con un programa que estoy haciendo para un trabajo.

```
static int MAX = 5;
static ArrayList<Integer>[] amistades = new ArrayList[MAX];

static List<Integer> solucion = new ArrayList<>();
static List<List<Integer>> soluciones = new ArrayList<>();

public RedSocial(ArrayList<Integer>[] amistades) {

    // Se construye una nueva instancia para buscar cadenas de amigos en una
    // población con las características especificadas por amistades.
    // Los individuos de la población se consideran numerados
    // consecutivamente 0,
    // 1, 2,...n-1, siendo n la longitud del array amistades.
    // Precondiciones: Para todos los valores amistades[i] (0 <= i < n) se
    // cumple
    // • amistades[i] es distinto de null y no tiene valores repetidos
    // • los elementos de amistades[i] son los índices de los amigos del
    // individuo i.
    // Por tanto, si la lista amistades[i] contiene un valor x,entonces 0 <=
    // x
    // < n
    // • Si a es amigo de b, entonces b es amigo de a. Por tanto, si la
    // lista
    // amistades[i] contiene un valor x, la lista amistades[x] contiene el
    // valor
    // i.

    ArrayList<Integer> amigos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
    amistades[0] = amigos;

    amigos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 3, 4));
    amistades[1] = amigos;

    amigos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1));
    amistades[2] = amigos;

    amigos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 2));
    amistades[3] = amigos;

    amigos = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0));
    amistades[4] = amigos;

    solucion = search(2, 4);
}

public List<Integer> search(int a, int b) {
    // Devuelve la cadena de amigos más larga que puede formarse entre los
    // individuos A y B, con las características indicadas arriba; null, si
    // no puede
    // formarse una cadena así.
    // Observaciones:
    // • si el resultado no es null, la lista resultante no contiene
    // elementos repetidos.
    // Es decir, una persona solo puede aparecer en la cadena una vez como
    // mucho.
    // • Si pueden formarse varias cadenas de amistades, cumpliendo los
    // requisitos
    // indicados, y con la misma longitud, devuelve una cualquiera de ellas.

    ArrayList<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, -1));
    DevuelveLista(lista, b, indices);
    return null;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RedSocial red = new RedSocial(amistades);

    System.out.println(soluciones.toString());
}

public static void DevuelveLista(List<Integer> solu, int b, List<Integer> indices) {

    List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista = amistades[solu.get(solu.size() - 1)];

    if (indices.size() > 1) {

        indices.set(indices.size() - 1, indices.get(indices.size() - 1) + 1); // aumento
                                                                                // en
                                                                                // uno
                                                                                // el
                                                                                // último
                                                                                // indice
        int hijo = indices.get(indices.size() - 1);

        if (amistades[solu.get(solu.size() - 1)].size() == indices.get(indices.size() - 1)) {
            // si el padre no tiene más hijos
            solu.remove(solu.size() - 1); // eliminamos hijo
            indices.remove(indices.size() - 1); // eliminamos hijo

            if (solu.size() > 0) {
                DevuelveLista(solu, b, indices);
            }

        } else {
            if (lista.get(hijo) == b && !solu.contains(lista.get(hijo))) {
                solu.add(lista.get(hijo));
                indices.add(-1);
                System.out.println("es respuesta!" + solu.toString());
                soluciones.add(solu); //NO GUARDA SOLU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                DevuelveLista(solu, b, indices);

            }
            if (lista.get(hijo) != b && !solu.contains(lista.get(hijo))) {
                solu.add(lista.get(hijo));
                indices.add(-1);
                DevuelveLista(solu, b, indices);
            }

            if (lista.get(hijo) != b && solu.contains(lista.get(hijo))) {

                DevuelveLista(solu, b, indices);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que no guarda `soluciones.add(solu)` y me devuelve los `List<Integer>` vacíos.

Comment: como evaluas que no se guarda? porque no veo que estes usando en ningun tro momento la variable "soluciones", o solo defines un breakpoint he inspeccionas la variable despues de pasar por el add()

Comment: En main muestro solucciones y me devuelve [[][][]]                     System.out.println(soluciones.toString());

Comment: Deberias documentar qué se supone que hace `DevuelveLista`, no es fácil de adivinar - la falta de documentacion es agravada cuando usas nombres de variables como `b` en la lista de argumentos.

Comment: Por otra parte, el `public RedSocial(ArrayList<Integer>[] amistades)` es problemático. Es un constructor? (en tu código falta el nombre de la clase). Si lo es, entonces es muy raro que èl argumento `amistades` sea (al parecer) una lista vacia a ser llenada por el mismo constructor Eso no tiene mucho sentido, en todo caso esa lista deberia quedar almacenada como campo del mismo objecto que se está construyendo. Por otro lado, el algoritmo de construcción es muy frágil (la consistencia se rompe fácil). De hecho creo que es incosistente (el elemento 1 es vecino del 4 pero el 4 no es vecino de 1?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea donde haces `soluciones.add(solu)`, debes colocar `soluciones.add(new ArrayList(solu))`, ya que como está actualmente estás pasando el **mismo objeto** "N" veces y si éste queda vacío o null, todos los elementos que agregaste a `soluciones` se modificarán ya que apuntan al mismo objeto.

Comment: Perfecto, con este simple cambio he conseguido corregir mi código, ahora funciona como yo quería. Una vez corregido esto prosigo con el programa para finalizarlo. Gracias!